# How can i do a "GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP" in Kusto?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, kql, azure-monitor-workbooks

In T-SQL, when grouping results, you can also get a running total row when specifying "WITH ROLLUP".

How can i achieve this in Kusto? So, consider the following query:

```
customEvents | summarize counter = count() by name
```

The query above gives me a list of event names, and how often they occurred. This is what i need, but i also want a row with the running total (the count of all events).

It feels like there should be an easy way to achieve this, but i havent found anything in the docs ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write 2 queries, the first query is used to count the number of each events, the second query is used to count the numbers of all the events. Then use the `union` operator to join them.

The query like below:

```
customEvents 
| count 
| extend name = "total",counter=Count
| project name,counter
| union
(customEvents 
| summarize counter = count() by name)
```

Test result is as below:

[image]